# jQuery .live and WebKit are crashing

Tags: jquery, webkit

I am loading audio players dynamically (via AJAX) which works well, the problem comes when a user is using Safari or Chrome on a mac. I can not get it to crash on FF on the mac or any windows browser. It seems that the live event is causing the issue, but I am willing to be wrong.

I wonder if one of the jQuery pros out there can help clear up my confusion which is leading to crashing.

This "audioplayerHTML5" is what is loaded dynamically.

```
$(function() {                      
    var stop = false;
    $(".loop").live('mousedown',function (event) {
        if (this.checked == false) {
            this.checked=true;
        }else {
            this.checked=false;
        }
    });
    $(".audioplayerHTML5").live('click',function (event) {
        if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) {
            playbutton = event.layerX < 31;
        }else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > 0){
            playbutton = event.offsetX < 61;
        }else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > 0){
            playbutton = event.offsetX < 31;
        }
        video = $('.videoplayer').get(0);
        if (this.paused == false && playbutton) {
            if ($('#syncMusic').is(':checked') && video != undefined) {
                video.pause();
            }
            this.pause();
        //check for play button pressing on initial
        }else if (this.paused == true && playbutton) {
            if ($("#last_played").val() == 0){
                $("#last_played").val(this.id);
                if ($('#syncMusic').is(':checked') && video != undefined) {
                    video.play();
                }
                if ($('#playAudioBeginning').is(':checked')) {
                    this.currentTime = 0;
                }
                this.play();
            }else if ($("#last_played").val() != this.id) {
                audio = $('#'+$('#last_played').val()).get(0);

                if (audio == undefined){
                    $("#last_played").val(this.id);
                    if ($('#syncMusic').is(':checked') && video != undefined) {
                        video.play();
                    }
                    if ($('#playAudioBeginning').is(':checked')) {
                        this.currentTime = 0;
                    }
                    this.play();
                }else{
                    audio.pause();
                    $("#last_played").val(this.id);
                    if ($('#syncMusic').is(':checked') && video != undefined) {
                        if ($('#playFromBeginning').is(':checked') && video.paused == false) {
                            video.currentTime = $( "#sliderVideo" ).slider( "values", 0);
                        }else{
                            video.play();
                        }
                    }
                    if ($('#playAudioBeginning').is(':checked')) {
                        this.currentTime = 0;
                    }

                    this.play();
                }
            }else if ($("#last_played").val() == this.id){
                if ($('#syncMusic').is(':checked') && video != undefined) {
                video.play();
                }
                if ($('#playAudioBeginning').is(':checked')) {
                this.currentTime = 0;
                }
                this.play();
        }

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you checking `event.layerX` for FF but `event.offsetX` for WebKit? jQuery normalizes all of the event properties so you shouldn't need to check different properties for different browsers.

On top of that, if you *are* going to try to sniff the user agent, and you're already using jQuery, [**use jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) to do it:

```
if($.browser.mozilla) {
    playbutton = event.layerX < 31;
}else if ($.browser.safari){
    playbutton = event.offsetX < 61;
}else if ($.browser.webkit){
    playbutton = event.offsetX < 31;
}
```

---

### Edit

There's a lot of room for improvement in this code. Here's a shot at fixing it up.

```
$(function() {
    $('.loop').live('mousedown', function() {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
    });

    $('.audioplayerHTML5').live('click', function(event) {
        var audio,
            playbutton, 
            video = $('.videoplayer').get(0),
            $syncMusic = $('#syncMusic'),
            $last_played = $('#last_played'),
            $playAudioBeginning = $('#playAudioBeginning'),
            $playFromBeginning = $('#playFromBeginning'),
            $sliderVideo = $('#sliderVideo');

        if ($.browser.mozilla) {
            playbutton = event.layerX < 31;
        } else if ($.browser.safari) {
            playbutton = event.offsetX < 61;
        } else if ($.browser.webkit) {
            playbutton = event.offsetX < 31;
        }

        if (!playbutton) return;

        if (!this.paused) {
            if ($syncMusic.is(':checked') && video) {
                video.pause();
            }
            this.pause();
            //check for play button pressing on initial
        } else if (this.paused) {
            if (!$last_played.val()) {
                $last_played.val(this.id);
                if ($syncMusic.is(':checked') && video) {
                    video.play();
                }
                if ($playAudioBeginning.is(':checked')) {
                    this.currentTime = 0;
                }
                this.play();
            } else if ($last_played.val() !== this.id) {
                audio = $('#' + $last_played.val()).get(0);

                if (!audio) {
                    $last_played.val(this.id);
                    if ($syncMusic.is(':checked') && video) {
                        video.play();
                    }
                    if ($playAudioBeginning.is(':checked')) {
                        this.currentTime = 0;
                    }
                    this.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    $last_played.val(this.id);
                    if ($syncMusic.is(':checked') && video) {
                        if ($playFromBeginning.is(':checked') && !video.paused) {
                            video.currentTime = $sliderVideo.slider('values', 0);
                        } else {
                            video.play();
                        }
                    }
                    if ($playAudioBeginning.is(':checked')) {
                        this.currentTime = 0;
                    }

                    this.play();
                }
            } else if ($last_played.val() == this.id) {
                if ($syncMusic.is(':checked') && video) {
                    video.play();
                }
                if ($playAudioBeginning.is(':checked')) {
                    this.currentTime = 0;
                }
                this.play();
            }
        }
    });
```

#### Assorted cleanup

- The `.live('mousedown', ...)` can be written *so much more simply*
- Cache jQuery objects, it's more efficient
- Be consistent with string delimiters; don't mix-and-match single and double quotes
- Multiple missing `var` keywords (`=>` declaring global variables, which is b-a-d **bad**)
- No need to check `video != undefined`, just check the truthiness of `video`
- Seriously, stop checking if a boolean value is equal to `true` or `false`, just check its truthiness
- Remove unused variables (namely `stop` and `event`)
- Use `return` statements (judiciously) to reduce excessive `if...else` nesting and redundant checks

#### Unresolved questions

- Is `.loop` checkboxes? If so, ditch the `.live('mousedown', ...)` handler. It is entirely superfluous.
- With all those UA checks, what is supposed to happen in IE?

#### Let's talk

This method is too damn big. Break it down into a series of smaller, more manageable functions. For example, you might turn this chunk of code:

```
if (!this.paused) {
    if ($syncMusic.is(':checked') && video) {
        video.pause();
    }
    this.pause();
    //check for play button pressing on initial
}
```

into a separate function call that looks like this:

```
if (!this.paused) {
    pause(this, $syncMusic.is(':checked') ? video : null);
}
```

where `pause` is the following function:

```
function pause(vidA, vidB) {
    if (vidB) {
        vidB.pause();
    }
    vidA.pause();
}
```

Comment: Matt, Those changes you made seemed to really help out a lot. I am still able to crash the browsers though. Would you be willing to help me out some more? The way the audio (HTML5 audio player) players are being brought in is via AJAX, passing the search criteria. I had hired someone to write the jQuery but I can see from your comments they did not know it as well as you do. Again thank you for the help and if there are other places in this code that can be cleaned up I would appreciate your help, or I can show you offline how it works, and we can get this crash bug cleared up.

Comment: I really don't see anything that screams "browser crasher" in the code. Would you be able to post a live link or a http://jsfiddle.net that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hm, I'm using Chrome 10.0.648.205 (the latest stable available) on OS X 10.6.7, and the page seems to work just fine for me. What exactly is the "crash" behavior? Does it show the [Chrome sad tab](http://i.imgur.com/1OStG.png)?

Comment: These are some youtube videos i was able to record that captured the crash. Same Chrome, yep getting sad tab. Same OSX, safari 5.0.5
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LwKFxxan0s
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4jXk-wdESE

Comment: Okay, I finally got it to crash in Safari, still can't get it to crash in Chrome... it looks like the crash is caused by a segfault somewhere deep in the browser's audio layer. This may actually be more that I can troubleshoot, since it really doesn't look like a JavaScript error. If you don't get any useful answers, you might consider opening a Chrome (or perhaps WebKit) bug report. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Matt, Thank you for the suggestion, I am glad it might be something deeper than the code. I have posted to that link like you said. Would you be willing to look offline at some more javascript and jQuery and see if it can be cleaned up of useless/redundant code?

Comment: I don't mind, but there's actually a whole SE site for code review that you'll probably get even better suggestions on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com. One thought I did have: the underlying problem (aside from a browser bug) might be the rapid loading/unloading large amounts of audio data. It might be worth seeing if loading individual files fixes it - by that I mean, don't load any audio for song results until the user actually clicks play. Then, only load that song's audio data. This will save your site bandwidth, and be easier on less powerful computers as well.

Comment: That worked well. Is there a way you know to change the word loading to "Press play"? I have reverted to the other code until I can finish this project, incase Google is also looking at the ticket i submitted.

Comment: You'd probably use [`.text('Press play')`](http://api.jquery.com/text), though I'm not sure where this "Loading" message is.

Comment: The loading message is in Safari player only. FF and Chrome do not show the message. Where would .text('Press play') go after?

Answer (score 1):

Solved from the crashing utilizing Matt Balls code addition plus adding

```
this.play();
```

After

```
} else if (this.paused) {
```

And before

```
if (!$last_played.val()) {
```

Also setting preload="none" for the audio player. this.play() loads the clicked track.

Matt, again thanks for the hard work and clarity and working together.

Comment: No problem! Sorry I couldn't be more useful in rooting out the actual source of the browser crash. +1 for the effort & good feedback.